# unable to edit hair with brush in particle edit mode

Tags: particles, hair

I created an object with a particle system (hair).But after a moment,the hair becomes impossible to edit,they still look grey in particle edit mode.I cannot use any brush or select the hair.Where does this problem come from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by going to Options and setting Editing Type to Particles